# Which BIP-148 branch is the most recommended?

Tags: segregated-witness, bip148-uasf

I want to run an BIP-148 ("segwit UASF") node. However, I am not sure which of the various branches is most maintained and recommended to run.

- There is [this pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/10532) by earonesty ([386 commits behind master](https://github.com/earonesty/bitcoin/), last commit May 30)
- There is [a *different* pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/10442) by earonesty (on luke-jr repo, [154 commits behind master](https://github.com/luke-jr/bitcoin/tree/bip148), last commit June 22)
- [There is also UASF/bitcoin repo](https://github.com/UASF/bitcoin) (1379 commits behind master, last commit July 2)

Which of these repos is the most recommended one?

(Note: this question might get outdated soon. For reference, I am asking it 3rd July 2017.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As luke-jr (author of the code in one of the PRs) said [in the comments right now](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/10532#issuecomment-312636228), the branch is abandoned and the recommended code is in [UASF/bitcoin repo](https://github.com/UASF/bitcoin/).

(Again the answer might get outdated soon.)